# What does "Is Identity" column property mean in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, properties

I am using **SQL Server** for the first time and I see that a column property is called **Is Identity**.

What does this mean?

What are the advantages of marking a column property as **Is Identity = Yes**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It simply means the column uses the `Identity(seed, increment)` function to provide values for a primary key (usually). It is also known as "Autonumber". The second line below is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Table (
TableID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
DateTimeStamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
Data nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    TableID ASC
)
```

It acts as a default value for the column that increments for each record. Note that you can also get the value inserted from SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Do not use @@IDENTITY as it is depreciated and can return the wrong result in the case of triggers or nested contexts.

Answer (score 4):

Flag indicating an Identity Column - can be used as an auto-increment column (recommended for any table)

it has many implications like being able to get the id of the last inserted row in a table using @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() etc.

Try: 
[Understanding Identity Columns](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-identity-columns)

Comment: i updated comment with some more information. don't forget to vote up the answer. Thanks

Comment: Don't use @@IDENTITY.  It's unreliable, if there is a trigger on the table which puts data into another table which has an identity column on it @@IDENTITY will return the wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

It's equivalent to MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT property.  Usually used on a primary key column