# How to give unique number in each Receipt of payment in one table of Database Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vba

I have a database, 3 or more tables and a one of them with 3 or more columns.

In this table i have ID column, Name Column, Date Column etc.

I like to select one record for printing and give to the person one or more Receipt of payment (bill).

But every time i like the number of Receipt to be unique. For all persons in my table and all payment.

The start number Format will be 00000000 or 00.000.000 or A 000000 . Next number +1 etc.

Ask for further explanation.

See Form example:

[image: form example]
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/89/prinreceipt.png/

Comment: This really isn't very clear. Do you need the unique number to start back at 1 (or 0) for each person, or is it a seperate Unique number that just continually incrememnts for each receipt no matter what person it is for? You could use a unique index in the DB and have a function that gets the larges number and increments it, if that is what you are trying to do, but I am not sure that is exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MS SQL-Server, i would use a Stored Procedure in database to insert new records and a CLR(scalar-valued function)to get the next bill-number. On this way you could ensure that the number is unique.

The SP could look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBill]
    @idBill int OUTPUT,
    @CreationDate datetime OUTPUT,
    @Name varchar(50) OUTPUT,
    @BillNumber char(10) OUTPUT
 with execute as Owner
AS
INSERT INTO tBill(CreationDate, Name, BillNumber)
VALUES (GetDate(), @Name, dbo.GetNextBillNumber())
;SELECT  @idBill=idBill,@CreationDate=CreationDate, @Name=Name, @BillNumber=BillNumber
FROM tBill WHERE (@idBill = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

The next number will be `MAX(BillNumber)+1`, the format is 10 chars(A+9 digits), the CLR to generate the next bill-number:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextBillNumber]()
RETURNS CHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BillNumber CHAR(10);
    DECLARE @nextBillNumber int;
    SET @nextBillNumber = CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING((SELECT MAX(BillNumber) FROM tBill),2,9)) + 1;
    SET @BillNumber = 'A' + RIGHT('000000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@nextBillNumber),9)
    return @BillNumber 
END
```

Note: not 100% tested but you should understand what i mean.

Edit: You also should [add a unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint/65123#65123) to guarantee the uniqueness. Then it's techniqually impossible to insert two records with the same Bill-Number. In this example i've presumed that the table's [primary-key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx) is not the Bill-Number itself but an int-column which  [Is Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548532/what-does-is-identity-column-property-mean-in-sql-server/548542#548542)(Auto-Increment, [here with SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359170/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-tables/3359186#3359186)).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) are informations on how to call a stored-procedure from ADO.NET.

Comment: +1 - Agreed - You should use your database to enforce integrity of the data and generate your unique identifier for you