# Is there anything fundamentally wrong with my database relations table?

Tags: sql, database

[image]

Would this be the correct layout for a diagram as such? A few of these tables share the same primary key, but I am not sure if this is the best practise/correct relationships that I should set out.

It's for a local level, whereby players don't change teams and assuming that player positions are final. The aim is to gather statistics to show later for analysis.

Comment: what happens when a player can play multiple positions?

Comment: @NathanHughes Actually, `Squad` only allows one row per team

Comment: The big question is what are your needs. soccer statistics may be extremely detailed and may be just keeping match scores.
Your diagram doesn't seem to handle players changing teams, or positions, or players playing a different position then the one they are used to, etc'. I've worked in the past on a soccer statistics application, my database was way, way more elaborate then this.

Comment: I think that the design is messed up. We can't really give much feedback without knowing your requirements. As it is, one player can have only one row in the `PlayerStatistics` table, and that table has the `Team_Id` there, why?; what's the deal with the `Squad` table?, why can you have only one row per team?

Comment: @Paparazzi where are you seeing this?

Comment: It's for a local level, whereby players don't change teams and assuming that player positions are final. The aim is to gather statistics to show later for analysis.

Comment: @Lamak I was wrong.  They can switch teams.  But that would be better handled in Players if that is the intent.

Comment: @A.McLean so, basically, the whole `PlayerStatistics` table can be incorporated in the `Players` table. And also the `Positions` table

Comment: @A.McLean Then add the comment to the question.

Comment: And I don't understand the `Squad` table, but, as it is, it can be merged with `Teams`

Comment: Squad is a clear problem and you have failed to include requirements.  Voting to close as this question cannot be answered with the information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Squad` table should be a linking table that creates a many to many relationship between `Players` and `Team`. Since each Player/Team combination can occur only once, both columns `Team_ID` and `Player_ID` should be part of the primary key.

`Squad` should be on the n-side of two relationships. Its name should probably be something like `Membership`.

---

Why do you need a separate `PlayerStatistics` table? Apparently it stores statistics for the same Player_ID/Team_ID combinations as `Squad`. The fields of this table should go to the `Squad` table.

---

Shouldn't the `Positions` be per membership? One position per membership, i.e. one player has one defined position in each team, in which case `Position_ID` should be a column in `Squad`.

---

There should be two relationships between `Team` and `MatchStatistics`. One on `Home_team_ID` and one on `Away_team_ID`.

---

[image]

---

Alternatively you could associate the `PlayerStatistics` to `Player` and `Match` and thus store what each player has done in each single game. You would then retrieve the overall player statistics or the player-per-team statistics through appropriate queries.

Comment: I don't see how the `Squad` table creates a many to many relationship, it's primary key is `Team_Id`, so it can be merged with the `Teams` table instead

Comment: The current design of the OP is wrong. As I say in my answer, the PK should be (Player_ID, Team_ID). Its purpose it to tell which player is in which team and each player can be in several teams and each team can have several players. This is why it **should** create a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Okay I have changed my layout to suit yours however I have entered a `LeagueTable` as well which has a Team_ID connecting to Team's Team_ID as a foreign key. Inside membership, which value do I use for is-identity? Also I have a button insert method that enters a team name for Team but I want it to create a record (with the same Team_ID) inside my `LeagueTable` (the rest of the values can be null except for its primary key League_ID)

Comment: I understand a league as a group of sports teams. Therefore there should be a `League_ID` in the `Team` table as foreign key. This forms a one (`League`) to many (`Team`) relationship. See: [What does “Is Identity” column property mean in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/548532/880990). Usually the Primary Key is an identity column, but only if it is not a foreign key. I.e. `Player.Player_ID` can be an identity column, but not `Membership.Player_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Messed up in my mind unless you have some strange requirements.

With this design a squad is limited to a single player.

Team_ID is associated with Statistics (not player).  If you want a player associated with a single team then do that in Players.  And then you should actually merge Statistics with Players.

A link on PK to PK between two tables is rarely a proper design.

If you want a player to be able to play on multiple teams then have PlayerID, TeamID a composite key in Statistics.

You need to disclose the requirements for a proper review. Squad is clearly messed up but you have not stated the purpose of squad.